# What is the probability of two out of three events happening?

Tags: probability

All events are independent.

$$\Pr(A) = \frac{9}{10}$$
$$\Pr(B) = \frac{9}{10}$$
$$\Pr(C) = \frac{6}{10}$$

`What is the probability of at least two events happening?`

I'd like to use negation, to negate the possibility that event no event happen plus the probability that only one happens.

$$D = \text{at least two events happen}$$

$$\Pr(D) = 1-\Pr(\text{none happens})-\Pr(\text{exactly one happens})$$

$$\Pr(D) = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{4}{10}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{6}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10} + \frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{4}{10} + \frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{4}{10}\right) = 0.918$$

The answer seems a little larger, I can't convince myself that I'm right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach works, and your answer is correct.

It can *also* be calculated straight forwards as:

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(AB\cup AC\cup BC)
& = \mathsf P(AB)+\mathsf P(A^cBC)+\mathsf P(AB^cC)
\\[1ex]
& = \mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B) + \bigg(\mathsf P(A^c)\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B^c)\bigg)\mathsf P(C)
\\[0ex]
 &= \frac{9^2}{10^2} + \bigg(\frac{1\cdot 9}{10^2} + \frac{9\cdot 1}{10^2}\bigg)\frac 6{ 10}
\\[1ex]
& = \frac{918}{1000}
\end{align}$

Comment: why is the first term not $P(ABC^c)$?

Comment: We require a union of disjoint events. $$AB\cup AC\cup BC=A(B\cup B^{\small\complement} C)\cup A^{\small\complement} BC$$ An outcome in the union is either in $A$ or not. If it is in $A$, then it is in $B$ or $C$ - which is to say in $B$ xor $B^{\small\complement}C$.  Else if not in $A$, then it must be in both $B$ and $C$.

Comment: @Jackson In short: We do not want to neglect the outcomes in all three events, $ABC$.$$AB\cup AC\cup BC=ABC\cup ABC^{\small\complement}\cup A B^{\small\complement} C\cup A^{\small\complement} BC$$

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm that is the right answer, calculated it directly and obtained the same number.